# Create an app that auto syncs data with server cordova javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, synchronization

I am developing an app which involves downloading huge amount of master as well as transactional data and the user can work offline/online based on net availability and when network is available the data has to be synced both ways( from sqlite to server and server to sqlite).

I have studied different approaches as to how to do this.
1.Keep a time flag to find the last time of sync and download only those records which are added after that time.This way initially on first time load only the data download will be slow.
2.Use options like html5sql to improve the insert time of records in sqlite.

But I am still doubtful as to how to make the auto sync work.Can someone enlighten me as to how to sync records maintaining the data integrity. I am using basic javascript ,HTML5 and mysql server.

Comment: there are a few plugins for hot code push

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use, [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/)? It will keep the data synced across your devices as per the subscription.